# StackOverflowError with a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, stack-overflow

Have the following insertion method for a left child - right sibling tree - seems to be causing a `StackOverflowError` at the line that called `addpage` again within the private version of the method. Can anyone help advise how it can be fixed? Sorry if this has been asked before.

```
public PageNode addPage(String PageName)
{
    PageNode ParentNode=new PageNode();
    ParentNode.page=currentPage.page;
    if (this.homePage==null)
        this.homePage=ParentNode.parent;
    else
        ParentNode=this.addPage(PageName,ParentNode.parent);
    return ParentNode;
}
private PageNode addPage(String PageName, PageNode ParentNode)
{
            ParentNode = new PageNode();
            ParentNode.page=new Page(PageName);

    if (this.currentPage.page.compareTo(ParentNode.page)==0)
    {
        System.out.println("attempt to insert a duplicate");
    }
    else
                    if (ParentNode.page.compareTo(currentPage.page)<0)

                        if(currentPage.firstchild == null)
            currentPage.firstchild=ParentNode;
                        else
                            ParentNode = addPage(PageName, ParentNode.firstchild);
                        else if(currentPage.nextsibling == null)
                                currentPage.nextsibling=ParentNode;
                        else
                                ParentNode = addPage(PageName, ParentNode.nextsibling);
            return ParentNode;
}
```

Comment: Consider fixing the code formatting; also if/else without `{}` can lead to subtle hard-to-spot bugs, esp. when nested like that. (I stop looking at a question if the code is hard to read.) That asside, the easiest way to "see" what causes a stack overflow is to see what each invocation is passed and how it fits into the call-stack. Use a debugger (or those primitive `println`'s).

Comment: What language is this supposed to be ? Consider tagging appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement a binary search tree. You should guarantee that insert/delete/lookup operations take `O(logn)` time in your search tree. Your `addPage` method doesn't rebalance the tree so in the worst case, the height of your tree is `O(n)`. See [Big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) if you are unfamiliar with the notation. Learn about Red-Black/AVL trees.

You are using recursion to add new nodes. As the height of the tree can get as big as `O(n)`, you exceed the limit on stack size.

I don't know the default upper bound on stack size per thread in JVM.

Comment: A good binary tree search will do as you suggest, but a merely functional one doesn't have to.  See Knuth for the definitive discussion and sample algorithms.

Comment: @ddyer Fixed wording to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite the methods to iterate instead of recurse.

Java doesn't implement tail recursion removal.